# Django Request is missing required authentication credential, 'status' :UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: django, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to social login with google,

```py
user_info = requests.get(
        f"https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"},
    )

    print(info.json())
```

```sh
{'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.', 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED'}}
```

using Django 
i wanna take user infomation and save my database and login
how can i do?

Comment: check the google api python client library, then go though the people api to get the data you need.

Comment: thank u!!  i will try it

Comment: https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python